# Use a spreadsheet to give information to HTML form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am new to JavaScript and was wondering if I could use a spreadsheet to send data to a html form. There would be a text box for the user to enter their name and I would like it to fill out email address, phone etc from the spreadsheet with an offset for different columns.

Comment: Where would the spreadsheet be located?  On the server or the end-user's PC.  How would javascript know where to find the spreadsheet?   If on the server, what server-side tech are you using?  Why do you think this would be a javascript/jquery solution?

Comment: The spreadsheet would be on the server. I don't know if JavaScript can do this, I'm just hoping it can.

Comment: It's a very simple server, no php, mysql etc. @freedomn-m

Answer (score 0):

Try [js-xlsx - spreadsheet parser and writer](https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx)

Comment: Would this be able to put data into text inputs?